# onClick method of checkbox turns icon into bitmap

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I have a listView of the users installed applications. In each list item, it has the application name, package name, icon, and a checkbox at the end. When the checkbox is checked, I want it to take the application icon from that listView item (i.e. if the application for "News" is checked, it would take the icon for the "News" application) and then turn it into a bitmap.

Please note that I am loading the necessary info like this:

```
/ load controls from layout resources
    ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
    TextView tvAppName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvPkgName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);
    final CheckBox addCheckbox = (CheckBox) v
            .findViewById(R.id.addCheckbox);
    Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Controls from layout Resources Loaded");

    // set data to display
    ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
    tvAppName.setText(entry.activityInfo.loadLabel(mPackManager));
    tvPkgName.setText(entry.activityInfo.packageName);

    Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Data Set To Display");
```

I have already tried this one way, but I am suspecting that it is not working the way I think it is, so I want a second opinion. Here is what I am currently doing:

```
addCheckbox
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.println("Checked");
                        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                        Drawable icon = null;
                        try {
                            icon = pm
                            .getApplicationIcon(entry.activityInfo.packageName);
                        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Drawable default_icon = pm.getDefaultActivityIcon();
                        if (icon instanceof BitmapDrawable
                                && default_icon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                            BitmapDrawable icon_bd = (BitmapDrawable) icon;
                            Bitmap icon_b = icon_bd.getBitmap();
                            BitmapDrawable default_bd = (BitmapDrawable) pm
                                    .getDefaultActivityIcon();
                            Bitmap default_b = default_bd.getBitmap();
                            if (icon_b == default_b) {
                                // It's the default icon
                                scaleDownBitmap(default_b, 100, v.getContext());
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Scale Bitmap Chosen");
```

But after thinking about it, can I do like this?:

```
if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.println("Checked");
                        ImageView imgV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
                        imgV.buildDrawingCache();
                        Bitmap default_b = imgV.getDrawingCache();
                                // It's the default icon
                                scaleDownBitmap(default_b, 100, v.getContext());
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Scale Bitmap Chosen");
```

Or even just something like this:

```
if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.println("Checked");
                        Bitmap default_b = ((BitmapDrawable)ivAppIcon.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                                // It's the default icon
                                scaleDownBitmap(default_b, 100, v.getContext());
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Scale Bitmap Chosen");
```

I need a second opinion on ways to do this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're having trouble with the Drawable to bitmap conversion? I cannot ( yet ) post a comment and ask you this. Therefore I'll risk a full answer:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final int   DEST_IMAGE_WIDH = 100;
    final int DEST_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 100;
    PackageManager           pm = getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo     appInfo = getApplicationInfo();
    Drawable            appIcon = pm.getApplicationIcon(appInfo);
    Bitmap              appBmp  = Bitmap.createBitmap(
              DEST_IMAGE_WIDH
            , DEST_IMAGE_HEIGHT
            , Config.ARGB_8888
            ); 
    // Creates a new canvas based on the image specifications
    // create just above.
    Canvas canvas               = new Canvas(appBmp);
    // (optional) Fills the entire canvas
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // You need to set bounds otherwise a 0,0 sized image would be draw.
    appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, DEST_IMAGE_WIDH, DEST_IMAGE_HEIGHT );
    appIcon.draw(canvas);

    /// Let's save to a .jpg file ...
    File file = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/test2.jpg");
    FileOutputStream out;
    try
    {
        file.createNewFile();
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        appBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        out.close();

        // Load back the image file to confirms it works
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( file.getAbsolutePath() );
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView1.setImageBitmap( bitmap );            
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e2 ) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();           
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem I was having (well...part of it). However, I do really apperciate the full answer because that helped me to get through what I am fully trying to do (the only difference being that I get the bitmap from the stream in another class).

I won't be able to test this out until tomorrow, so I'll keep you updated then.

Thanks again! :)